# Transform Rails params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to transform Rails params?

I have a URL like `@some-user/posts/1`

Users have the decorated `@` in the URL.

But, Users are saved without the `@` like.. `some-user`

So I need to look up the post via username without the `@`.

Currently, I have..

```
def url_params
  params.permit(:username, :id)
end
```

Is there a best way to tranform the params for later use? In this case, remove the `@`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to remove the `@` is like this:

```
‘@some-user’[1..-1]
```

As @jvillian has stated, this may not be the ‘best’ way, depending on your idea of ‘best’. For example, if you’re using Ruby 2.7, you can also use:

```
‘@some-user’.delete_prefix(‘@‘)
```

Maybe this is the ‘best’ way.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this one.. I like this the best :)

```
def user_name
  params[:username].gsub('@', '')
end
```